# Join the same table with two different column laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, mysql-workbench

I try these code in MySQl:

```
SELECT      
     A.*, 
     B.name,
     C.name
FROM 
     eventlog_tbl as A
     LEFT JOIN users B ON A.byuser=B.email 
     LEFT JOIN users C ON A.affectiveuser=C.email;
```

I try these in Laravel

```
return DB::table('eventlog_tbl')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.byuser')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'users.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.affectiveuser')
            ->select('eventlog_tbl.*','users.name','users.name')
            ->get();
```

How can i convert it to Laravel?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries), have a go, post your code and we'll help from there.

Comment: @fubar how can i use these mysql script in laravel??

Comment: the most barbaric way: `DB::raw()`

Comment: @TheRock - did you even read the documentation? Because if you did, it shows you examples.

Comment: @fubar: Please look my update question. i can't get result

Comment: You will need to fix the method name for `leftJoin` (notice camelcase). And I believe the `users` will need to have an alias to ensure a unique name. What do you mean `I can't get result`?

Comment: @fubar: can you show me your answer because i am new with laravel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$res =  DB::table('eventlog_tbl')
        ->leftjoin('users AS A', 'A.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.byuser')
        ->leftjoin('users AS B', 'B.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.affectiveuser')
        ->select('eventlog_tbl.*','A.name as byuser_name','B.name as affectiveuser_name')
        ->get();

    print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your query written using the Laravel query builder.

```
$events = DB::table('eventlog_tbl')
    ->select('eventlog_tbl.*', 'users_1.name', 'users_2.name')
    ->leftJoin('users AS users_1', 'users_1.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.byuser')
    ->leftJoin('users AS users_2', 'users_2.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.affectiveuser')
    ->get();
```

Edit:

```
$events = DB::table('eventlog_tbl')
    ->select('eventlog_tbl.*', 'users_1.name AS user_1', 'users_2.name AS user_2')
    ->leftJoin('users AS users_1', 'users_1.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.byuser')
    ->leftJoin('users AS users_2', 'users_2.email', '=', 'eventlog_tbl.affectiveuser')
    ->get();
```

The problem is that both name columns are called the same thing. As per the accepted answer, these will need to be aliased differently too.

Comment: What should i write in my laravel blade because when i write these i still get the same user

Comment: <tr>
  <td>By User </td>
  <td>Affective User </td>
</tr>

@foreach($events as $value)
   <tr>
      <td>
      {{$value->name}}
   </td>
   <td>
      {{$value->name}}
   </td>
   </tr>
@endforeach

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert this to use relationships? I have probably got the relationships wrong, something like this:

```
class EventLog extends Model
{
    public function byUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'byuser', 'id');
    }

    public function affectiveUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'affectiveuser', 'id');
    }
}
```

And then

```
$event_log = EventLog::with(['byUser', 'affectiveUser')->all();


foreach ($event_log as $item) {
    echo $item->byUser->email();
}
```